# Disable Marlin PID, and start print manual

Tags: marlin, thermistor, pid

The thermistor of the hotend of my printer broke, at the moment I have no way to replace it, due to the global situation with the virus.
In my hands I have one of these [industrial PIDs](https://www.mpja.com/download/rex-c100.pdf) which is Temperature controller+K-type couple+SSR.
Is there a way to disable the PID in Marlin and start printing manually when the PID reaches the desired temperature? I just need it for PLA right now.
This way I can use the printer at least until I can replace the thermistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the temperature control commands out of your gcode, or just tell your slicer to omit them, typically by setting temperature to 0. Then, as you suggested, start the print manually once your industrial PID tells you it's at-temperature.

Comment: so I just need to remove the `M104 S...` that was simple, thanks a lot. I will do it tomorrow